# Pdf data extraction from scanned pdf using python

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract, pdfminer, pdf-extraction

I was extracting data from scanned pdf by tesseract ocr and I am able to extract data but the accuracy is not good. At many places, its showing wrong data so can I get data with 100% accuracy by python.

first I convert pdf to jpg format then I extract data from the image using tesseract module.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

text=(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r"C:\Users\sumesh\Desktop\ip\ip\pdf11.jpg")))
text=repr(text)
text=text.replace(r"\n","")
print(text)
```

I expected proper data from pdf but I am getting different data for eg.z is showing 2,5 is s,1 is I, etc

Answer (score -1):

Hope the below small changes will help you.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

text=str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r"C:\Users\sumesh\Desktop\ip\ip\pdf11.jpg"),lang='eng'))

text=text.replace("\n","")

print(text)
```

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but it would be more helpful if it also included *why* it's the correct answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Please use "DPI=500" after your file path, it might help..
For more info you can follow my answer posted here [How to convert .png images to searchable PDF/word using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627249/how-to-convert-png-images-to-searchable-pdf-word-using-python)