# How to convert .png images to text using Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract, pytesser, img2pdf

Recently, I took a project. Converting a scanned PDF to searchable PDF/word using Python tesseract.

After few attempts, I could able to convert scanned PDF to PNG image files and afterwards, I'm struck could anyone please help me to convert the PNG files to Word/PDF searchable.[my piece of code attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3q0S.jpg)

Please find the attached image for reference.

```
Import os
Import sys
from PIL import image
Import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string

 Libpath =r'_______' #site-package
 Pop_path=r'_______' #poppler dlls
 Sys.path.insert(0,LibPath)

  from pdf2image import convert_from_path

     Pdfpath=r'_______' # PDF file directory
     imgpath=r'_______' #image output path

     images= convert_from_path(pdf_path = pdfpath, 
         dpi=500, poppler_path= pop_path)
      for idx, of in enumerate (images):
                 pg.save(imgPath+'PDF_Page_'+'.png',"PNG")
                 print('{} page converted'.format(str(idx)))

       try:
          from PIL import image
       except ImportError:
                 import image
         import pytesseract

     def ocr-core(images):
              Text = 
       pytesseract.image_to_string(image.open(images))
       return text
  print(ocr_core("image path/imagename))
```

that's it, I've written.....then I got multiple ".PNG" images...now I can only able to convert one PNG images to text.

How to convert all the images and save it in CSV/word?

Comment: It would be much better if you copy/paste your code here. It also would be helpful if you describe result/error you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to my question

```
from PIL import Image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract


Pdf_file_path = '_______' #your file path

Images = convert_from_path(Pdf_file_path, dpi=500)

Counter=1
for page in Images:
       idx= "image_"+str(Counter)+".jpg" ##or ".png"
       page.save(idx, 'JPEG')
       Counter += 1

 file=Counter-1
 output= '_____' #where you want to save and file name
 f=open(output, "w")
 for i in range(1,file+1):
          idx= "image_"+str(Counter)+".jpg" ##or ".png"         
          text=str(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(idx)))
          f.write(text)
 f.close()
```

Comment: will it give us searchable pdf or just a text file which converted using tessseract ocr